# Attempt to borrow on in-active pool Using hector with cassandra

Tags: jsp, netbeans, glassfish, cassandra, hector

When i try to run the [SchemaManipulation](https://github.com/zznate/hector-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/riptano/cassandra/hector/example/SchemaManipulation.java) example provided by the hector wiki, when the server is started the first time the server is run everything works perfectly, however after a second run errors occur (full stack trace below)

Im trying to connect to cassandra 1.0.7 using hector 1.0.2 and Glassfish 3.1.
I'm using  Netbeans 7.1.

Custom [JARs](http://prikachi.com/images/92/4405092n.png) that have been imported

First run (successful):

```
SEVERE: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.CassandraHostRetryService).
SEVERE: log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
INFO: Dropped key space
INFO: Name: WOO
INFO: RF: 1
INFO: strategy class: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy
INFO:   CF Type: STANDARD
INFO:   CF Name: DynamicCf
INFO:   CF Metadata: [ThriftColumnDef[name=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=8330 lim=8339 cap=9252],validationClass=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,indexType=KEYS,indexName=birthdate_idx]]
INFO:   CF Type: SUPER
INFO:   CF Name: SuperCf
INFO:   CF Metadata: []
```

Full stack trace error:

```
SEVERE: me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HInactivePoolException: Attempt to borrow on in-active pool: <ConcurrentCassandraClientPoolByHost>:{localhost(127.0.0.1):9160}
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.ConcurrentHClientPool.borrowClient(ConcurrentHClientPool.java:69)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.operateWithFailover(HConnectionManager.java:235)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.AbstractCluster.describeKeyspace(AbstractCluster.java:199)
    at net.zanity.live.SchemaManipulation.main(SchemaManipulation.java:40)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:68)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

SEVERE:     at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.ConcurrentHClientPool.borrowClient(ConcurrentHClientPool.java:69)
SEVERE:     at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.operateWithFailover(HConnectionManager.java:235)
SEVERE:     at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.AbstractCluster.describeKeyspace(AbstractCluster.java:199)
SEVERE:     at net.zanity.live.SchemaManipulation.main(SchemaManipulation.java:40)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:68)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
SEVERE:     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
SEVERE:     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
SEVERE:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The jsp page:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" import="net.zanity.live.*;" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><% out.println("AAAA"); %></h1>
        <%// SchemaManipulation.main(new String[0]); %>
        <%
        /*
            InsertSingleColumn ins = new InsertSingleColumn();
            String temp = ins.Insert();
            out.print(temp);*/
        SchemaManipulation.main(new String[0]);
        %>
        <h1><% out.println("AAAA2 :D"); %></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to using the SchemaManipulation example and lack of Cassandra experience, ive not realised that the example shuts down the cluster once it has finished executing.

This closes open pools and kills the conndection, for anyone else that comes accross this, just dont shut down the cluster at the end of the class

```
//remove this as it kills the cluster.
cluster.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

Comment: Thanks! This was what I exactly anticipated. But when do you invoke shutdown() if running the Web app under a servlet container? Or you don't invoke it at all, as the Web app gets killed when the application server is bounced, which means the connection is returned to the pool by default?

Comment: @asgs Well, first thing I wana say is, this is over a year and a half old, you should try to use diffrent drivers if possible. `.shutdown()` tells the api to kill all the connections used, so whenever your application exists, you would shut down the connection pool, which for your example, a web app, is never really, unless you are switching servers or updating your host running the webapp.

Comment: Right, the server switch/update happens almost once in a month. I'm not sure what is the time period between which the shutdown() has to be invoked and when it has to be renewed. I guess I won't invoke it as the App servers are frequently updated or restarted.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer extension:

**There is nothing wrong with shutting down the connection pool**.
For example, to me, it is a necessity to clean up my tests resources.

**The real mistake was that you shut it down improperly!**

---

As you can find on [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hector-users/92wmgc4s8a0), calling:

```
cluster.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

Only **marks** the connection as removed, but does not actually remove it from `Cluster` object that still contains a reference to this connection in the pool. (Only marked with shutdown state.)

**To properly shut down the connection**, you should have called:

```
HFactory.shutdownCluster(cluster)
```

with this helper method, `cluster` will no longer contain a link to the dead connection and it will create a new one when it is necessary.

---

But obviously, if there is no reason to close the connection, or you want to reuse it later, simply do not delete it at all ;-).